# The number of item s corresponding to the day postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

How to make a table as follows?

table: item

| id | region_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2020-11-10 |
| 2 | 1 | 2020-11-11 |
| 3 | 3 | 2020-11-10 |
| ... | ... | .... |

Result: the number of items corresponding to the day

| region_id | 2020-11-10 | 2020-11-11 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |  |
| 3 | 1 | 0 |  |

Comment: [Crosstab questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+and+%28%5Bpivot%5D+or+%5Bcrosstab%5D%29)

Comment: I have a lot of days

Comment: Then you'll have to write a lot of column expressions

Comment: You "have a lot of days". That is why formatting the results should be left to the presentation layer not the database.

Answer (score 0):

you can use either `crosstab` or you can use `group by` :

```
select region_id
       , MAX(case when date = '2020-11-10' then 1 else 0 end) as "2020-11-10"
       , MAX(case when date = '2020-11-11' then 1 else 0 end) as "2020-11-11"
       , MAX(case when date = '2020-11-12' then 1 else 0 end) as "2020-11-12"
       , ...
from table
group by region_id
```

if you don't want to dynamically generate the column list , you have to use `dynamic sql` either with group by or crosstab.